# classes - newbie at classes "this."

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm very new at classes. Below is an attempt to create a StageObject class that I can set width, height, xy, and background color.

```
 package 
    {
        import flash.display.MovieClip;



public class StageObjects extends MovieClip
    {


        public function StageObjects()
        {
            // constructor code
        }
        public function setUpStageObject(w:int, h:int, X:int, Y:int, color:Number):void
        {
            this.width = w;
            this.height = h;
            this.x = X;
            this.y = Y;

            this.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            this.graphics.beginFill(color,1);
            this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
            this.graphics.endFill();
            this.opaqueBackground = color;
            trace("parameters: " + w + " - " + h + " - " + X + " - " + Y + " - " + color);


        }

        /*~~~ adjust position and scale functions ~~~*/
        public function adjustXY(ch:Object, par:Object):void
        {
            var w = par.width;
            var h = par.height;

            ch.x = par.x + (w - ch.width) / 2;
            ch.y = par.y + (h - ch.height) / 2;
        }

        public function adjustWH(ch:Object, par:Object):void
        {
            var w = par.width;
            var h = par.height;

        }

    }

}
```

In the main timeline (Flash) I do this:

```
var titleBkg:StageObjects = new StageObjects();
titleBkg.setUpStageObject(imageBoxWidth, titleBkgHeight, -1, imageBoxHeight +1, 0x589199);
this.addChild(titleBkg);
```

But it doesn't show up. Did I reference "this." wrong?

Comment: setting the width/height of an empty movie clip has no effect. You can remove `this.width = w; this.height = h;`

Comment: How to I give the clip content?

Comment: Sure if you don't need any of the functionality of a movieclip just use a sprite.

Comment: sorry, edited the question above (change it to Sprite?) while you were answering.. I have done so, but it still comes up as having no width/height

Comment: Did you check the values of `w/h` that are used here `this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,w,h);` If they are not 0 then your sprite should have a non-zero width height after the drawing.

Comment: just commenting out the width and height declaration actually worked. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't create and parent your graphic properly with addChild.

Effectively your stage looks like this:

```
Stage ¬
    0: MainTimeline:MovieClip ¬
        0: instance1:StageObjects
```

And it needs to look like this:

```
Stage ¬
    0: MainTimeline:MovieClip ¬
        0: instance1:StageObjects ¬
            0: instance1:Shape
```

Your graphics call should be called on a shape, not a movieclip. You can also do this setup on the first call with one line rather than two.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class StageObjects extends MovieClip {
        public function StageObjects(w:int, h:int, X:int, Y:int, color:uint) {
            // Constructor
            this.x = X;
            this.y = Y;

            var rect:Shape = new Shape();
            rect.graphics.beginFill(color,1);
            rect.graphics.drawRect(0,0,w,h);
            rect.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(rect);
            trace("parameters: " + w + " - " + h + " - " + X + " - " + Y + " - " + color);
        }


        public function adjustXY(ch:Object, par:Object):void {
            // adjust position and scale functions
            var w = par.width;
            var h = par.height;

            ch.x = par.x + (w - ch.width) / 2;
            ch.y = par.y + (h - ch.height) / 2;
        }

        public function adjustWH(ch:Object, par:Object):void {
            var w = par.width;
            var h = par.height;
        }
    }
}
```

And creating the object would be simplified as:

```
var titleBkg:StageObjects = new StageObjects(imageBoxWidth, titleBkgHeight, -1, imageBoxHeight +1, 0x589199);
this.addChild(titleBkg);
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I'm starting to get this... (cue ominous music)

Comment: okay, what if I wanted to create another class "SwapableObject" that extends StageObjects. Can I do this: 'var newswap:SwapableObject = new StageObjects(widthamount, heightamount, xlocation, ylocation, color);'

Comment: You should, though you may need to call super() on the extended class (I don't recall).  Give it a try.  :)

Answer (score -1):

I suppose you had declare width, height, graphics etc. in constructor. In my class code I've never use 'this.'. If variable is declared as class private/public compiler will not allow you declare anfother varialbe with the same name. So you don't have to use 'this.', but it's more readable when you use 'this.' (you will know it's class variable). 
Have you add yor graphics to stage (not titleBkg, but object that you create inside titleBkg object)? ;)

Comment: I need the graphics (Sprites aka StageObjects) to be scaleable based on stageWidth/stageHeight values so can't add them directly to stage.

Comment: You should *always* use the `this` keyword. It puts an extra constraint on scope when looking for the object's memory reference. Yes, you do not *have to* use the keyword, but it should result in slightly faster object lookup times.